# React Native splash screen on ios

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, splash-screen

I am developing an app using react native and trying to add a splash screen on ios. I have added the following code on AppDelegate.mm

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"eCare";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  [RNSplashScreen show]; //Added this line

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

My app is stuck in the splash screen after this. I hid the splash screen on the root screen of react native. I followed the official guide [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the [doc](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) of the lib and I saw a difference of your code of the AppDelegate. See that at the end of the method `didFinishLaunchWithOptions`, there is a `return YES`, try to put this instead of  `return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];` and see if it works. If it doesn't work please answer so we can try to find another answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

switch return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

with the below...

bool didFinish=[super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

[RNSplashScreen show];  // here return didFinish;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).